# Pointer disappeared after passing to some functions (even with malloc)

Tags: c

My problem is that I created a pointer at the bottom Main.

Main will call load() to read input from a dictionary and insert the words in a inputfile into a TRIE *dict by calling insert() and getnode(). However, after load() return true, the *dict lost all of the value and I cannot get what I expected(i.e. showing cat is present as it is in my dictionary input file).

I have read from other websites that pointers can retain its value after doing malloc. So I have malloced for the *dict. Please kindly let me know why the value disappeared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHAR_TO_INDEX(c) ((int)c - (int)'a')

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])

struct dict
{
    char words[46];
    struct dict* dictPath[26];
    bool isEndOfWord;
};


// Returns new trie node (initialized to NULLs)
struct dict *getNode(void)
{

    struct dict *pNode = NULL;
    pNode = (struct dict *)malloc(sizeof(struct dict));

    if (pNode)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            pNode->dictPath[i] = NULL;
    }

    return pNode;
}

void insert(struct dict *root, const char *key)
{
    int level;
    int length = strlen(key);
    int index;

    struct dict *pCrawl = root;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
    {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
        if (!pCrawl->dictPath[index])
        {
            pCrawl = malloc(sizeof(struct dict));
            pCrawl->dictPath[index] = getNode();
        }
        printf("%i\n",index);
        pCrawl = pCrawl->dictPath[index];
    }

    // mark last node as leaf
    pCrawl->isEndOfWord = true;
}

// Returns true if key presents in trie, else false
bool search(struct dict *root, const char *key)
{
    int level;
    int length = strlen(key);
    int index;
    struct dict *pCrawl = root;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
    {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);

        if (!pCrawl->dictPath[index])
        {
            return false;
        }

        pCrawl = pCrawl->dictPath[index];
    }

    return (pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isEndOfWord);
}

bool load(struct dict *root, char *inputfile){

    // open the dictionary file
    FILE *infile = fopen(inputfile,"r");
    int dictchar;
    char tmpword[46];
    int cnt = 0;

    root = getNode();

    // start iterating to read char
    do
    {
        // read the character
        dictchar = fgetc(infile);
        if (dictchar != '\n')
        {
            // assign the dictionary character to a tmpword. tmpword will be used to fit into TRIES later
            tmpword[cnt] = dictchar;
            cnt ++;
        }
        // if the character is '\n', fit tmpword into TRIES
        else
        {
            tmpword[cnt] = '\0';
            cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(tmpword); i++)
            insert(root, tmpword);
        }
    } while (dictchar != EOF);


    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    struct dict *root = malloc(sizeof(struct dict));
    load(root, argv[1]);
    char output[][32] = {"Not present in trie", "Present in trie"};
    printf("%s --- %s\n", "cat", output[search(root, "cat")] );
    return 0;

}
```

p.s. I took reference from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Comment: You probably need to pass a pointer to the `dict *`

Comment: Try to create a [mcve]

Comment: but at the bottom: load(root, argv[1]);
I have already passed root to the load() function, or do I misunderstand your meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you function,

```
bool load(struct dict *root, char *inputfile)
```

you pass a `root` pointer, but then replace it with the result of `getNode`.
The calling code will not see this change.
You need to pass a pointer to the root pointer,

```
bool load(struct dict **root, char *inputfile)
```

for the calling code to see the change.

More simply, since you throw away the `root` with

```
root = getNode();
```

right near the top of the function, you could change the `load` signature:

```
struct dict * load(char *inputfile)
```

Instead of `return true;` at the end, `return root;` instead.
You don't have a path returning flase anyway.

Change the calling code too.
Instead of

```
struct dict *root = malloc(sizeof(struct dict));
load(root, argv[1]);
```

try this:

```
struct dict *root = load(argv[1]);
```